# Pass through AWS CloudFront viewer request headers to s3 origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

As per AWS documentation, aws cloudfront viewer request headers are passed to the s3 origin,
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorS3Origin.html

I have a vue static site hosted in s3 and distributed using cloudfront. AWS documentation is not very clear on how I can access these view request headers in my static sit. I do see the implementation of using the viewer request using Lambda @ Edge, but my use case is different.

As per Lambda @ edge, event object is accessible to the lambda, but is I'm not sure how I can access the cloud front request to the s3 origin for me to extract the headers from it.

any help will be appreciated !

Comment: You can turn s3 server access logging

Comment: thanks , my understanding is server access logging is for CloudFront logs. my question was on how to access these headers at s3 origin static site

Comment: Only AWS would be able to access these headers, not your static website as its only front-end view, not backend.